# Problem in using a custom header to all my Volley requests

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I want to make an Auth header for ALL my Volley requests
I have learnt how can I create a header overriding the getHeaders of the request class but I can not change it from every request from time to time and want to make it sort of static or global where I can change it and it changes everywhere. Here is what I have tried so far.

Main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue requestQueue;
JsonObjectRequest jsonreq;
JSONObject object;
  try{

                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

                object=new JSONObject();
                jsonreq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        res=response.toString();
                        Log.d("log1","res : " + res);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("log1","Error from response : " +error.networkResponse.statusCode);

                    }


                }) {
//want to get rid of this function from here and create in a global scope so I can control its implementation everywhere
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                          Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put("Authorization","xxxxxxxx");
    return params;

                    }
                };


               requestQueue.add(jsonreq);    

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("log1","error from catch " + e);
                return e.toString();
            }
            return res;
```

I tried making a custom class that extends HurlStack and override the execute request. Here is the code for custom HurlStack class called GlobalHeaders

```
public class GlobalHeaders extends HurlStack {
    String testing="xxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    public HttpResponse executeRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("Authorization",testing);
        return super.executeRequest(request, headers);
    }
```

Now I am not sure how can I make use of this method in my main class where I am adding the requestQueue(jsonReq);
I tried other way were I override Request class of Volley with my custom class but again failed.
Please point how can I make this work or any other approach. I am a new learner to Java and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have tried and this solution seems to work out. Posting here so It may also help someone in future.

Removed the getHeader method from the Main activity as the execute request gets called itself when I added its instance into the request using the below code.

```
 if(stack == null){
                    stack=new GlobalHeaders();
                    requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),stack);
                    requestQueue.add(jsonreq);

                }
```

Also need to change the first line in executeRequest method to cater the null exception to following

```
 Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(additionalHeaders);
```

and keep the return statement unchanged.